# Hashes: testing a key

Tags: perl, hash

A program reads a very large dictionary-style TXT file into a hash. Sometimes, there is a lower case version of a key that is preferable. My solution below is clumsy because it searches twice even if we already know the `lc` version exists:

```
if ( exists $hash{ lc $key } ) {
   $key = lc $key;
}
if ( exists $hash{ $key } ) {
    # lot of code involving $key
}
else {
    # the key doesn't exist, other code
}
```

Is there a way to avoid two `exists` tests? If `lc $key` exists I want to do the identical code to it as in the second `if` but I need to know which version, `lc` or not, of `$key` to use. I'm hoping to condense it to one `if-else` pair.

Knowing the case of the valid key is important for the rest of the program since it is used to look up information in another hash.

Comment: Does this mean you could have both `foo` and `FOO` as keys in the same hash at the same time?

Comment: Yes. This is a hash of names and words. Some names are also words. So if the user provides "John" and "john" exists as well, then "john" is what I'm after. I then use "john" to search the values of another hash and provide all the keys of that hash associated with "john" but not "John".

Comment: Normalize the keys as you're reading them in into a search index, but it probably isn't worth it. Two hash lookups is not expensive compared to the larger expenses. Or put the file into SQLite and use SQL (this will solve a lot of problems).

Comment: Hash1 has: John - WORD1, john - WORD2. Each key in Hash1 exists as a value in Hash2. TRANSLATION1 - john, TRANSLATION2 - john, TRANSLATION3 - John. But I'm culling only translations for "john", not for "John". Hence the need to preserve case. I hope that explains it better! I didn't know hash lookups weren't affected by hash size, so maybe my issue isn't an issue after all :)

Comment: Reopened. The OP doesn't want a hash with case-insensitive keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( my ($real_key) = grep { exists($hash{$_}) } lc($key), $key ) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

or

```
my $real_key =
     exists($hash{ lc($key) }) ? lc($key)
   : exists($hash{ $key     }) ? $key
   : undef;

if (defined($real_key)) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Sure, it still searches twice, but so what? You could use List::Utils's `first`, but I think replacing a hash lookup with a sub call could actually slow down the code!

Comment: Is using `exists` twice on a hash not a performance issue after all? I was looking for an alternative because the hash has over 250,000 entries.

Comment: @Erik Olson, Hash lookups are O(1), meaning they aren't affected by the size of the hash.

Comment: Two hash lookups are probably easier to read and faster to process than a tricky one-liner then. Just for my own edification, does `grep` in your example return lowercase `$key` in one step if valid or does it also check plain old `$key` every time? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are trying to compare your code to mine (even though both do two hash lookups),  I actually find a trivial use of `grep` far clearer than the very unusual code structure and variable reuse you have. I would make a double-take if I saw your code ("Is this actually correct?"). I've added a solution that doesn't use `grep` to my answer, but you really should start practicing using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`first`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#first) from [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util). It will return the first list element where the result from the code block is a true value, or `undef` if the block never returns true.

```
use List::Util qw(first);

$key = first { exists($hash{$_}) } lc($key), $key;

if (defined($key)) {
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
$key = do { my $temp = lc $key; exists $hash{$temp} ? $temp 
      : ( exists $hash{$key} ? $key : undef) };

if ( defined $key ) {
    # lot of code involving $key
}
else {
    # the key doesn't exist, other code
}
```